# What format of image?

Tags: image, binary

[Files Link](https://mega.nz/#F!uShEGCaC!RmfduG86iC9wpphRUDLojA)

I have binary image file. Its lightmap.
I know first 8 byte ist 2 int. Width and Height. 128x128
Next 4 byte its int value too. But I dont know what exacly. 
Next ist byte array. At end of file indexes like 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 3
I think indexes its for model.

Lightmap always grayscale.

What format of this file or how I can read this binary, how to get know length of byte array?

Comment: Maybe if you provided a link to the program or device that produces these things.... ?

Comment: Its a game. Pathologic HD